# аналог cron-а на php

Tags: php, ооп, инспекция-кода

В погоне за скоростью выполнения и меньшим потреблением памяти написал скрипт (аналог cron-a).

Хочу попросить вас посмотреть сей кусок кода и написать, что и как можно улучшить, от чего нужно избавиться.

Вот [код](https://github.com/Jaredjaxson/croner/blob/master/croner.php):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
    define ("CONST_TIME",1);// in second

    class croner 
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->start_on = time();
        }

        public function GetTime($i)
        {
            if(is_numeric($i)){
                $time = $i + $this->task->$i->last;
                if(time() >= $time)
                {
                    $this->task->$i->last = time();
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            if(strpos($i,':') !== false){ // and is_numeric(str_replace(':','',$i))
                // 
                if($this->task->$i->next == 0){
                    if(date('H:i') <= $i){
                        $this->task->$i->last = time();
                        $this->task->$i->next = time() + GetTimeAtr('d');
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }else{
                    if($this->task->$i->next >= time()){
                        $this->task->$i->last = time();
                        $this->task->$i->next = time() + GetTimeAtr('d');
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function GetTimeStart()
        {
            return $this->start_on;
        }

        public function AddTaskClock($time,$f,$p,$name)
        {
            $this->task->$time->start = time();// время начала,старта таска
            $this->task->$time->last = time(); // время последнего вызова таска
            $this->task->$time->func = $f;     // функция вызова 
            $this->task->$time->param = $p;    // параметры для ф. вызова
            $this->task->$time->taskname = $name;// имя таска
            $this->task->$time->next = 0;       // время следующего выполнения
            return true;
        }

        public function FindTask()
        {
            foreach($this->task as $key => $value)
            {
                if($this->GetTime($key)){
                    $this->CalledFunc($key);
                } 
            }
        }
        public function CalledFunc( $i )
        {
            return call_user_func(
                        $this->task->$i->func,
                        $this->task->$i->param  );
        }
        private function GetTimeAtr( $a )
        {
            switch ($a)
            {
                case 'm' :$r = 60; break;
                case 'h' :$r = 3600; break;
                case 'd' :$r = 86400; break;
                case 'w' :$r = 604800; break;
                case 'M' :$r = 2629743; break;
                case 'y' :$r = 31556926; break;
            }
            return $r;
        }

        public function StartCron(){
            while( TRUE ) {
                $this->FindTask();
                sleep(CONST_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: На этом сайт есть специальный раздел под названием Code Review. Вот туда и обращайтесь со своим вопросом.

Comment: ООП, скорость выполнения и потребление памяти - никак не связаны. Более того, ООП скорее даст просадку этих параметров по сравнению с хорошо написанным процедурным кодом. Преимущества ООП совершенно в другом.

Comment: Чтобы научиться ооп нужно программировать на языке, в котором нет ничего кроме классов. Чтобы не было никакой возможности сползти в процедурщину. А что много лишнего - так ничего страшного. В следующий раз на другой программке сделаете поменьше. Если и так работает, то и фиг с ней. Нечего время терять, надо дуть вперед.

Comment: @Sergey не согласен. Чтобы научиться ООП, надо чтобы тебя посадили за красивый ооп-проект на доработки. Чуток потрешкодишь, чуток попинаают тебя, и научишься. А на любом "чисто-ООП" языке можно написать синглтон на 100 методов, что понимания - явно никак не прибавит.

Answer (score 2):

**Краткий Review:**

1. Нет соблюдения стандартов PSR (наименование функций, переменных)
2. Неоднозначность в работе функции (множественные точки выхода из функции return TRUE or FALSE)
3. Свойство $task явно не определенно, является по сути массивом, но реализовано почему-то обьектом, и это позволяет мне обратиться к нему через $croner->task и сделать изменения (**Нарушение принципа OCP в SOLID**)
4. Нет документирования параметров,  я немогу понять, что мне нужно передавать, не открыв код.
5. Некоторые функции, которые системные, сделаны public.
6. Некоторые функции принимают у вас и строку и число, неоднозначность параметров.
7. Нарушение принципа DRY (**не повторяйся**) в строках $this->task->$i->last,  $this->task->$i->next функции GetTime
8. Более адекватное решение было сделать массив tasks, где хранить элементы какого-нить класса Task.
9. Мысли: "Я не понимаю, почему функция GetTime мне ничего не возвращает, я же явно вызвал функцию GetTime, написано get, а почему она ничего не вернула мне?" **Проблемы в отражении функциональности на название.**

А вообще подобные библиотеки наверняка есть на github, и легче взять уже написанный функционал, чем писать свои велосипеды.

Comment: Спасибо за критику.